# GameKit client/server issues with more than 3 clients

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gamekit, gksession

I am currently building an iOS application that allows users to share content with friends using GameKit. One device becomes the Sever and they can then send things to the connected peers. This is working well up until 4 connected clients.

The 4th Client can always join and receive one file but then it seems to ignore all other packets and crash with no error or crash log produced (have to force close application).

Before starting on the project I read that several developers had issues with more than 4 connections in P2P but there were no reports of this with Client Server (I read up to 16 players).

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug relating to iOS 6. The problem occurs when there is a mixture of iOS5 devices and iOS 6 devices all connected. It tends to be fine until around 4 players then random disconnections happen.

Several people have reported on the apple developers forums (for those of you with accounts - https://devforums.apple.com/thread/170210)

Answer (score 0):

```
GKMatchTypePeerToPeer -> 4  (maximum players)
GKMatchTypeHosted     -> 16 (maximum players)
GKMatchTypeTurnBased  -> 16 (maximum players)

This example (http://www.raywenderlich.com/12976/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-7) is GKMatchTypeHosted
```

Comment: I am using Server Client mode. So I should be able to get up to 16 players right?